# Is it possible to run Visual Studio Database Edition schema migrations from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, schema-compare, schema-migration, datadude

Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition (Data Dude) has the ability to perform schema comparisons between databases and generate a script which migrates from one database to the other. Is it possible to perform this comparison and generate the migration script from the command line? If so, what are the command line tools, and are the same tools used in equivalent versions of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VSDBCMD tool [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) might answer your problem.